# redirect_uri_mismatch in django all auth

Tags: redirect, django-allauth

Hi I am facing redirect_uri_mismatch in django all auth I have given this url in google console setting

http://localhost.com:8000/accounts/social/google/login/callback/

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Application: Stylavie

You can email the developer of this application at: 

The redirect URI in the request: "http://localhost.com:8000/accounts/social/google/login/callback/" did not match a registered redirect URI.

Learn more

Request Details
That’s all we know.
```

Comment: Its not path.com its localhost

Answer (score 1):

Wait for sometime to propagate the changes and then it will work.